# Color calibration greyed out in Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, colors

I'm using an external display with my Asus Vivobook which has an inbuilt display of 1920*1080 resolution. Now, unlike Windows 10 where I could calibrate the inbuilt display by going to Intel graphics settings, in Ubuntu there is no such things and as such the default display of the laptop is straining my eyes. The whites are very washed out and there seems to be little contrast. The external display I have can be calibrated by its internal settings and I've done that.

Is there a way I could calibrate colors for the laptop? The calibrate button is greyed out and I've learnt that I need a colorimeter for that? I've installed `redshift` but that hasn't affected the inbuilt display. Can someone point me in the right direction? (It's really hurting)